# Checking if an Angular resource response is empty

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that returns a promise. I would like to check if the value returned is an empty object. How can I achieve this. I guess I need to extract the returned value from the promise object somehow.

Here's my resource:

```
app.factory('Auth', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('/user/identify', {}, {
      identify: {
        url: '/user/identify'
      },
    });
  }
]);
```

Then in a service:

```
Auth.identify(function(data) {

  // This always passes since data contains promise propeties
  if (!_.isEmpty(data)) {

  }
});
```

A console log of data gives:

```
Resource
  $promise: Object
  $resolved: true
  __proto__: Resource
```

I can check for expected properties when the object is not empty but would like a more generic method.

Comment: did you try `if(!data.length)`

Comment: @charlietfl - that returns undefined whether or not there is data.

Answer (score 0):

To unwrap the return value you can access the promise directly:

```
Auth.identify()
    .$promise
    .then(function(data) {
      if (!_.isEmpty(data)) {
        // ...
      }
    });
```

Comment: Nope - data is still a resource object with properties as in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You're so close. You shouldn't call the response "data" when it is in fact a *Resource* object, which looks a lot like the `Resource` object you posted:

```
$resource('/api/...').get({...}).then(function(response) {
  if (response.data) {
    // the response has a data field!
  }
}

// note: this is using query(), which expects an array
$resource('/api/...').query({...}).then(function(response) {
  if (response.length > 0) {
    // the response data is embedded in the response array
  }
});
```